# Search and replace and overwrite inside XML file using powershell

Tags: powershell

**Statement:**  Have a JMX file which content type is XML and want to replace a particular value inside the file and save it in the same directory from where I am reading from (***note**: more specific want to overwrite the same file with the new value*).

**JMX [XML Content] File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.5">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="AliceImageOperation[IQCP &amp;PFR For 2 Users] 9:15" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">true</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath">./security.jar</stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers"/>
      </HeaderManager>
      <hashTree/>
      <CookieManager guiclass="CookiePanel" testclass="CookieManager" testname="HTTP Cookie Manager" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="CookieManager.cookies"/>
        <boolProp name="CookieManager.clearEachIteration">false</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="CookieManager.controlledByThreadGroup">false</boolProp>
      </CookieManager>
      <hashTree/>
      <Arguments guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="Input Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
          <elementProp name="base_scheme" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">base_scheme</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">http</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="base_port" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">base_port</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">8080</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="Test_Name" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">Test_Name</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__P(Test_Name,LOADTEST01)}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="Test_Triggered_By" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">Test_Triggered_By</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__P(Test_Triggered_By,PerfAdministrator)}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="Project_Name" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">Project_Name</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__P(Project_Name,LocalTest)}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="test_Id" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">test_Id</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__P(test_Id,Run01)}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="uniqueScenario_Id" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">uniqueScenario_Id</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__P(uniqueScenario_Id,MIB_StudyCreation_R01)}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
        </collectionProp>
      </Arguments>
      <hashTree/>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

**Code Block:**

```
function fetchBuildNumber() {
    $pat ="<pat_value>"
    $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)")) }
    $UriOrganization = "<url>/_apis/build/builds?api-version=7.2-preview.2"  
    $ProjectsResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $UriOrganization -Method get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader
    
    $succeededBuildNumber = @()
    $ProjectsResult.value | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.result -eq 'succeeded') {
            $succeededBuildNumber += $_.buildNumber
            $newUniqueScenarioIdForPerfTest = 'perf_'+$succeededBuildNumber[0]
        }   
    }
    return $newUniqueScenarioIdForPerfTest 
}

function fetchUniqueScenarioIdFromTheTestPlanAndUpdate() {
    
    $testPlanLocationJMX = "<LocaltionOfJMX File>"
    $xmlJMX = [xml](Get-Content $testPlanLocationJMX)
    $uniqueScenarioID = $xmlJMX | Select-Xml "//elementProp[@name='uniqueScenario_Id']//stringProp[@name='Argument.value']" 
    $getScenarioValue = $uniqueScenarioID -match ".*,(.*?)\)}.*" 
    if ($getScenarioValue) {
            $fetchCurrentScenarioID = $matches[1] 
            
        }
    return $fetchCurrentScenarioID
}

fetchUniqueScenarioIdFromTheTestPlanAndUpdate
```

Want to replace the `$fetchCurrentScenarioID` with the `$newUniqueScenarioIdForPerfTest` which is `MIB_StudyCreation_R01` with `perf_20231017.5` in this example and overwrite it on the same file.

Answer (score 1):

Try Xml Linq

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test1.xml"


$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)

$elementProp = $doc.Descendants('elementProp') 

$name = $elementProp | Where-Object { $_.Attribute('name').Value -eq 'elementProp' }

$argValue = $name.Elements('stringProp') | Where-Object { $_.Attribute('name').Value -eq 'Argument.value' }

$value = $argValue.Value

$pattern = '(?<prefix>[^(]+\()(?<key>[^,]+,)(?<value>[^)]+)(?<suffix>.*)'

$newValue = $value -replace $pattern,'${prefix}${key}perf_20231017.5${suffix}'

$argValue.SetValue($newValue)

$doc.Save($outputFilename)
```